django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac
On my Django drf application, I am using multiprocessing library to run background task. Its working fine in the development. In production when worker start to execute I receive the following error message.
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]: Process Process-1:
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]: psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     self.run()
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/api/helpers/multiprocessing.py", line 84, in worker_for_reconcile_view
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     if unmatched_mr_serializer.is_valid():
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 775, in is_valid
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 634, in run_validation
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     value = self.to_internal_value(data)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 693, in to_internal_value
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     validated = self.run_child_validation(item)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 653, in run_child_validation
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     return self.child.run_validation(data)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 442, in run_validation
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     value = self.to_internal_value(data)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 499, in to_internal_value
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 155, in run_validation
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     return super().run_validation(data)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 540, in run_validation
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     value = self.to_internal_value(data)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 259, in to_internal_value
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     return queryset.get(pk=data)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 645, in get
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     num = len(clone)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:           ^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 382, in __len__
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     self._fetch_all()
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1928, in _fetch_all
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 91, in __iter__
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     results = compiler.execute_sql(
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1562, in execute_sql
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     cursor.execute(sql, params)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     return super().execute(sql, params)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     return self._execute_with_wrappers(
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:   File "/var/www/html/recon/reconcilation/backend/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
May 28 12:29:48 localhost uvicorn[38322]: django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac

This is my background worker code:
import django
django.setup()
import os
from django.db import transaction
from api.helpers.adduserdetail import add_detail
from api.serializers import (
    MatchedTransactionSerializer,
    UmatchedPosSerializer,
    UnmatchedMrSerializer,
    ReconcilationSerializer,
)
from api.models import Unmatched_Pos
import multiprocessing
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
import asyncio


def start_worker_for_reconcile_view(
    matched_transaction,
    have_pos_data,
    unmatched_Pos,
    user_id,
    company_id,
    name,
    unmatched_mr,
    reconcilation_data,
):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=worker_for_reconcile_view,
        args=(
            matched_transaction,
            have_pos_data,
            unmatched_Pos,
            user_id,
            company_id,
            name,
            unmatched_mr,
            reconcilation_data,
        ),
    )
    process.start()


def worker_for_reconcile_view(
    matched_transaction,
    have_pos_data,
    unmatched_Pos,
    user_id,
    company_id,
    name,
    unmatched_mr,
    reconcilation_data,
):
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend.settings')
    with transaction.atomic():
        add_detail(matched_transaction, user_id, company_id, name)
        errors = []
        for item in matched_transaction:
            matched_transaction_serializer = MatchedTransactionSerializer(data=item)
            if matched_transaction_serializer.is_valid():
                matched_transaction_serializer.save()
            else:
                errors.append(matched_transaction_serializer.errors)

        if have_pos_data == True:
            Unmatched_Pos.objects.all().delete()
        else:
            pass
        print("sucessfully saved matched transaction")
        add_detail(unmatched_Pos, user_id, company_id, name)

        unmatched_pos_serializer = UmatchedPosSerializer(data=unmatched_Pos, many=True)

        if unmatched_pos_serializer.is_valid():
            unmatched_pos_serializer.save()
        else:
            print("error occured while saving the unmatched pos data")

        print("saved unmatched pos sucesfully")
        add_detail(unmatched_mr, user_id, company_id, name)

        unmatched_mr_serializer = UnmatchedMrSerializer(data=unmatched_mr, many=True)

        if unmatched_mr_serializer.is_valid():
            unmatched_mr_serializer.save()
        else:
            print("error ocurred while saving the unmatched mr data")

        print("unmatched mr sucessfully")

        reconcilation_serializer = ReconcilationSerializer(data=reconcilation_data)

        if reconcilation_serializer.is_valid():
            reconcilation_serializer.save()
        else:
            print("errro occured while saving reconcilation entry")

        print("all work done")
        run_async(send_message_to_client("reconciliation completed successfully"))


async def send_message_to_client(message):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    group_name = "reconcilation"
    await channel_layer.group_send(
        group_name,
        {
            "type": "reconcilation_message",
            "message": message,
        },
    )


# Utility function to run the coroutine in a non-async context
def run_async(coro):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if loop.is_running():
        asyncio.ensure_future(coro)
    else:
        asyncio.run(coro)



Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Tried to close all the db conncections before the worker starts to execute  so the child process will not try make the connection from parent. and it worked well
